# Kotlin is not allowing the instantiating of parent Nested classes through sub or derived classes

Tags: java, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

Currently I am shifting some code from java to kotlin and I came across a problem that is Nested classes can not be initialized through derived class of Out class while Java Allow so. The code Elaborate it well

```
/// Java Outer Class
public class JavaOuterClass {


static class InnerClass{

    }

}
/// Java derived Class
public class JavaDerivedClass extends JavaOuterClass {
}
///Java Class Initialization in main method
public class JavaTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
   JavaOuterClass.InnerClass instance = new JavaOuterClass.InnerClass();
//inner class is allowed to instantiate through outer class 
   JavaDerivedClass.InnerClass instance1 = new JavaDerivedClass.InnerClass();
   }
}
```

I can Initialize the nested class through derived class.While in kotlin

```
//Kotlin outer class
open class KotlinOutClass(){
lateinit var name:String;

init {
    this.name = "outerClass"
}

class InnerClass() {

    fun InnerClassMethod() {
        print("InnerClass method")
    }

  }
}

//Kotlin derived class



class KotlinDerivedClass(): KotlinOutClass() {

fun subClassMethod(){
    print("subClassMethod")
  }
}
```

Now I can not initialize the nested class in parent class through derived class class of outer class

```
 ///kotlin Class Initialization in main method
class KotlinTestClass {

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
   var instance: KotlinOutClass.InnerClass = KotlinOutClass.InnerClass();
   var instance1: KotlinDerivedClass.InnerClass = KotlinDerivedClass.InnerClass();
  }

}
```

[image]

java is allowing this behavior but doing same is no allowed in kotline. could any one let me know why is not possible in kotlin, if it is how?

Comment: Please read [no pictures of exceptions](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/) / [no pictures of code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Then use the [edit] link to replace screen shots of text with nicely formatted/indented text within your question.

Comment: @GhostCae The code is already provided but just want to more elaborate how it looks in the IDE